# APT doesn't autoremove an automatic package with 0 dependents

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, postgresql

```
$ apt install postgresql-11
$ apt purge postgresql-11
$ apt autoremove
```

if you execute these commands on a fresh Ubuntu or Debian installation you will find that a dependency named `postgresql-client-11` wasn't autoremoved along with other the dependencies despite having no dependents.

```
$ apt rdepends postgresql-client-11 --installed
```

returns nothing!

Same for `postgresql-12`.

This doesn't happen with `aptitude`.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Use what is described here `man  apt-get | less -p fix-broken` maybe...

Comment: unfortunately, didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `dpkg --remove`  too? It is in the same text.

Comment: I'm able to remove the package manually. What I want to know is why "apt autoremove" doesn't remove it.

Comment: Well, you would probably have had to investigate that BEFORE actually removing it.

Comment: I repeated the experiment many times with different distros and package versions. I tried everything. I contacted a debian dev and a postgresql maintainer who couldn't explain what's going on. I even filed a bug report at APT mailing list that initially got a response but then was ignored. I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: I can confirm the issue. Probably it is a bug.

Comment: Fortunately, not a bug, just a postgresql configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postgresql-common` configures apt to not autoremove postgresql packages.

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-postgresql:

```
APT
{
  NeverAutoRemove
  {
    "^postgresql-";
  };
};
```

https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/all/postgresql-common/154/file/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-postgresql